# Enable / disable internet activity programmatically on iMac

Tags: xcode

I have bee searching for a way to Enable / Disable internet activity using Xcode on my iMac, maybe I am using the wrong key words so that may be my problem. Any help is appreciated.

greatly appreciated JZ

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can totally disable internet.
You can turn off the Wi-Fi..

```
[[CWInterface interface] setPower:NO error:nil];
```